# How would I display the time ago that a post was made with the simple_form gem - Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to display the date that a post was made in my Rails site, how would I display say '1 day ago' etc and 'less than a day ago' for anything under a day.

I'm using the simple_form gem and am very new to Rails so not sure what to do. Any help with this would be really appreciated!

My code is as follows:

house_controller.rb -

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @houses = House.page(params[:page]).per(20).order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def new
    @house = House.new
  end

  def create
    @house = House.new(params.require(:house).permit(:title, :price, :location, :beds, :property, :available, :description, :image))
      if @house.save
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render "new"
      end
  end
end
```

house.rb -

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true
    validates :location, presence: true
    validates :property, presence: true
    validates :beds, presence: true
    validates :available, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "300x300", thumb: "150x150#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

index.html.erb -

```
<% @houses.each do |house| %>

  <div class="house">
    <%= image_tag house.image.url(:large) %>
    <h2><%= house.title %></h2>
    <h2>&#163;<%= house.price %></h2>
    <p><%= house.location %></p>
    <p><%= house.beds %></p>
    <p><%= house.available %></p>
    <p><%= house.property %></p>
    <p><%= house.description %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb -

```
<%= simple_form_for @house, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :title, label: "House title" %>
  <%= form.input :price, label: "House price" %>
  <%= form.input :location, label: "Town, County" %>
  <%= form.input :beds, label: "No. of Bedrooms" %>
  <%= form.input :available, label: "House available from" %>
  <%= form.input :property, label: "Property Type e.g Flat, Bungalow" %>
  <%= form.input :description, label: "Describe your house" %>
  <%= form.input :image, as: :file, label: "Image of house" %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you can use rails-timego gem, form has nothing to do with it:

https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago

```
<%= timeago_tag @house.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 1.day.ago %>
```

if you'll set up correctly you'll have the time updated automatically by javascript. a minute ago, 2 minutes ago, etc.. up to 1 day, then it will be 1 day ago, 2 days ago, etc..

Comment: Ah right i see thank you and where in which file do I need to put the <%= time ago_tag @house... %> in?

Comment: Depends where you want to show it, if it's index.html, it will be `<%= timeago_tag house.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 1.day.ago %>` inside the loop or if it's show.html page it will be like in my answer.. everywhere as long as you have the house object.

Comment: Ok so i've placed - <%= timeago_tag house.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 1.day.ago %> - inside my index.html.erb inside <div class="house"> but I've just done a test post a few minutes ago but its saying 'about 14 hours ago'? Any idea why? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could be related to timezone, you need to set the timezone in application.rb or it will take UTC. `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada) # your zone here'`

Comment: run `rake time:zones:all` to see all available zones

Comment: rake time:zones:all returns - rake aborted! No makefile found.

Comment: so if I wanted to have it set to English GMT how would i write that within the application.rb file and whereabouts within it?

Comment: require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'


Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Sellmyhouse
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end

end

Comment: 1st - run `rake time:zones:all` into a rails app folder, not anywhere you like it. 
2nd - there is no such thing as English GMT
3d - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: Sorry realised I wasn't in the right directory. So if I wanted UTC +00:00  then what would I put in config.time_zone = '...'?

Comment: By default is `UTC +00:00` but in this case I am not sure why you have 14 hours for a recently created post.

Comment: hmm, thats what I thought, because at the moment I have Eastern time in there but that is 14 hours ago anyway